# What does '"templated": false' mean for Spring Boot Actuator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

For `Spring Boot` **3.1.1** - about *Actuator*, if is executed the `/actuator` endpoint in a Web Browser, it shows by default the following:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/actuator",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/actuator/health",
            "templated": false
        },
            "health-path": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/actuator/health/{*path}",
            "templated": true
        }
    }
}
```

Observe that for each path/uri always appears the `"templated": false` part. BTW It appears when the other endpoints are *exposed* too

**Question**

- What does `"templated": false` mean for Spring Boot Actuator?

**Extra Questions**

- What is the purpose of this field?
- Where and how is used/interpreted this field?
- How to change to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

```json
{
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator",
         "templated":false
      },
      "health":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health",
         "templated":false
      },
      "health-path":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/{*path}",
         "templated":true
      }
   }
}
```

where `health-path` is templated: meaning, you can specify which detail you want to see.

If you create a custom endpoint, templated will automatically be `true` if you add a second `@ReadOperation`

```java
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "hello")
public class SayHello {

    @ReadOperation
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    @ReadOperation
    public String who(@Selector String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

}
```

with result:

```json
 ...
 "hello-name":{
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/hello/{name}",
    "templated": true
 },
 "hello":{
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/hello",
    "templated": false
 },
 ...
```

Comment: Oh carambas, the latest one was "true" - very tired around here ... Yes, I've confirmed the same for the other endpoints with the same category- Therefore the value is according how is generated the URI of the endpoint

Comment: Huge thanks for the addition!